# Java: Instance of Class B in Class A where Class B uses variables declared in Class A

Tags: java, class, robotics

AutoRedBuilding class declares instance variables leftMotor, rightMotor and foundationServo. RobotMover class contains methods that use those instance variables and I would like to call the RobotMover methods in AutoRedBuilding.

Specifically, the instance variables declared in AutoRedBuilding are actuators like motors and servos. RobotMover is a class that contains methods which move the actuators in a certain way such as driving forward and turning. I would like to somehow call the RobotMover methods in AutoRedBuilding.

I've tried making the AutoRedBuilding variables public, then creating an instance of RobotMover in AutoRedBuilding but that didn't work (code below). Example error message (I get the same error message for all the actuator variables):

```
RobotMover.java - cannot find symbol
symbol: leftMotor
```

```
// Copyright (c) 2019 Terrace BroBots. All rights reserved.

package org.firstinspires.ftc.teamcode;

import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.Autonomous;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.LinearOpMode;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.DcMotor;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.Servo;

@Autonomous(name="Autonomous: Red Building Zone", group="SkyStone")

public class AutoRedBuilding extends LinearOpMode {

    // declare hardware variables
    public DcMotor leftMotor;
    public DcMotor rightMotor;
    public Servo foundationServo;

    @Override
    public void runOpMode() {
        // initialise hardware variables
        leftMotor = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "leftMotor");
        rightMotor = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "rightMotor");
        foundationServo = hardwareMap.get(Servo.class, "foundationServo");

        // wait for game to start
        waitForStart();

        /* 
        THIS IS WHERE RobotMover CLASS METHODS ARE CALLED
        */
        RobotMover mover = new RobotMover();
        mover.driveForward(10, 1);
        mover.driveReverse(10, 1);
        mover.turnRight90();
        mover.turnLeft90();
        mover.clipFoundation();
        mover.unclipFoundation();
    }
}
```

```
// Copyright (c) 2019 Terrace BroBots. All rights reserved.

import java.lang.Math; 

public class RobotMover {

    // unit conversion rates
    private double robotWidthCm = 0;
    private double wheelRadiusCm = 0;
    private double degree90ToCm = (2 * Math.PI * robotWidthCm) / 4;
    private double cmToTicks = 2240 / (2 * Math.PI * wheelRadiusCm);

    public void setMotorPowers(double leftPower, double rightPower) {
        leftMotor.setPower(leftPower);
        rightMotor.setPower(rightPower);
    }

    public void driveMotorDistances(double cmLeftDistance, double cmRightDistance, double power) {
        // reset encoders
        leftMotor.setMode(DcMotor.RunMode.STOP_AND_RESET_ENCODER);
        rightMotor.setMode(DcMotor.RunMode.STOP_AND_RESET_ENCODER);

        // convert cm to ticks and set target position
        int tickLeftDistance = (int) Math.round(cmLeftDistance * cmToTicks);
        int tickRightDistance = (int) Math.round(cmRightDistance * cmToTicks);
        leftMotor.setTargetPosition(tickLeftDistance);
        rightMotor.setTargetPosition(tickRightDistance);

        // drive until position is reached 
        setMotorPowers(power, power);
        while(leftMotor.isBusy() && rightMotor.isBusy()) {}
        setMotorPowers(0, 0);
    }

    /*
    THESE ARE THE METHODS CALLED IN AutoRedBuilding CLASS
    */

    public void driveForward(double cmDistance, double power) {
        driveMotorDistances(cmDistance, cmDistance, power);
    }

    public void driveReverse(double cmDistance, double power) {
        driveMotorDistances(-cmDistance, -cmDistance, power);
    }

    public void turnRight90() {
        driveMotorDistances(degree90ToCm, 0, 0.8);
    }

    public void turnLeft90() {
        driveMotorDistances(0, degree90ToCm, 0.8);
    }

    public void clipFoundation() {
        foundationServo.setPosition(0.5);
    }

    public void unclipFoundation() {
        foundationServo.setPosition(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: *but that didn't work* - why do you mean? Do you have some errors, if so please share.

Comment: @ScaryWombat added error message

Comment: See the [mcve] definition -- we ask that your questions contain only the **shortest possible code** that allows others to reproduce a specific problem. Doing that right generally means removing anything that's related to the larger program you're trying to build, and focusing *only* on reproducing the problem you're asking a question about. (If the language-level issue can be reproduced with no robotics-specific details, the robotics-related elements should be removed before the question is asked).

Answer (score 0):

If you want `RobotMover` to know about these variables then they need to be passed to this class either in the constructor or as `setter` methods

e.g.

```
RobotMover mover = new RobotMover(DCMotor left, DCMotor right);
```

The `RobotMover` will need to have corresponding fields